# Cypress and Applitools: [Eyes test not started] : Error: Request failed with status code 400(Bad Request)

Tags: cypress, applitools

WHen doing an eyesCheck using the cypress applitools package I get the error:
[Eyes test not started] : Error: Request failed with status code 400(Bad Request)

I also get no screenshots shown in the test batch when I run (in applitools).

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Thanks.

Comment: cypress code line causing issue: cy.eyesCheckWindow({
        ignore: [
          {selector: "input[ng-model='selectedEmployee.startDate']"}
        ]
      });

Comment: cypress applitools package used: https://github.com/applitools/eyes.sdk.javascript1/tree/master/packages/eyes-cypress

Comment: Show your code.